# Yii2. Custom class validator

Tags: validation, yii2

I implemented a custom class validator "**app\validators\TestValidator**". In what place of the configuration file it is necessary to register to enable validation in the model?
For example: ['field', 'test'].
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
['field', TestValidator::className()]
```

sure you should add **USE** to be able to autoload this validator in your app or

```
['field',app\validators\TestValidator::className()]
```